# Is there a way to use the preprocessor to generate an operator like + or - from ascii number for symbol, without including that symbol?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

So I am trying to obfuscate some c code, and I'm wondering if there is a way to generate an operator like & (for address), or + or - (for addition/subtraction) etc, from it's hex/octal/decimal code in ascii, without resorting to some sort of table or something that includes the character.

Ideally this would work like the following if it wasn't obfuscated:

```
#define ADD(a, b) (a HEX(0x2b) b)
//so ADD(10, 2) expands to 10 + 2
```

Comment: I think you're out of luck if you want a pure C solution. You would need to mention '+' somewhere. I tried to hack it with universal character names (which let you write `\uXXXX` to get the Unicode character at codepoint XXXX -- it needs `-fextended-identifiers` to work with `g++`), but you can't specify '+' that way (universal character names only work with certain characters). It wouldn't work with a macro either.

Comment: Err, with `gcc`. I think they were added in C99 for C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the direct question is "no". The only operations the preprocessor can perform *at all* are substitution and concatenation; everything else has to be built up from these, and that means that even things like [arithmetic](https://github.com/VesaKarvonen/order-pp/blob/master/inc/order/prelude/nat_tables.h) need to be implemented by lookup tables behind the scenes.

This doesn't necessarily mean you can't obfuscate the program in the way you have in mind though. After all, ASCII itself is kind of just a lookup table too. So this isn't a question of *capability* so much as it is one of misdirection. There are several ways you could try to conceal the existence or meaning of an operator lookup table.

e.g. layering a few misdirections together-

`platforms/other/std-compat.h`:

```
#ifndef __GNU_C__

// non-GCC systems can't rely on this being provided automatically
#define MEM_INIT_MAP (int[]){ \
    (0x112a8)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a8)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a9)+MEM_INIT_END, (0x11505)+MEM_INIT_END, \
    (0x112a0)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a0)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a0)+MEM_INIT_END, (0x11517)-MEM_INIT_END, \
    (0x112a1)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a1)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a9)/MEM_INIT_END, (0x11505)+MEM_INIT_END, \
    (0x112a2)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a2)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a0)+MEM_INIT_END, (0x11517)%MEM_INIT_END, \
    (0x112a3)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a3)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a9)|MEM_INIT_END, (0x11505)&MEM_INIT_END, \
    (0x112a4)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a4)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a0)+MEM_INIT_END, (0x11517)+MEM_INIT_END, \
    (0x112a5)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a5)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a9)>MEM_INIT_END, (0x11505)+MEM_INIT_END, \
    (0x112a6)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a6)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a0)+MEM_INIT_END, (0x11517)<MEM_INIT_END, \
    (0x112a7)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a7)*MEM_INIT_BASE, (0x115a9)^MEM_INIT_END, (0x11505)+MEM_INIT_END, \
}
#define MEM_INIT_BASE   // sentinel: will be redefined by OS header
#define MEM_INIT_END    // similarly??/
#include <vmmem/protect_init.h>

#endif
```

main file:

```
#define OP_IMPL STR(CAT(platfo, CAT(rms/othe, CAT(r/std-comp, at.h))))
#define STR(S) STR_(S)
#define STR_(S) #S
#define CAT(A, B) CAT_(A, B)
#define CAT_(A, B) A ## B
#define EAT(...)
#define ID(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define SELECT(X, ...) CAT(SELECT_, X)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define SELECT_0(_0, ...) _0
#define SELECT_1(_0, _1, ...) _1
#define SELECT_2(_0, _1, _2, ...) _2
#define SELECT_3(_0, _1, _2, _3, ...) _3   // etc.

#define OP(X) ID(EAT SELECT(X, CAT(MEM_, CAT(INIT_, MAP))))

#include OP_IMPL

10 OP(2) 2   // expands to 10 + 2
```

Here the lookup table is hidden in an intimidatingly system-looking file. Abuse of `CAT` and `STR` hides the fact that the file is used at all from a simple `grep` (or that the main program references the macro defined therein). The lookup table itself is defined within an `#ifndef` block that most people will assume is unused (the real `__GNUC__` has no middle underscore), and made to look like an array initializer rather than a preprocessor list (it is still a valid preprocessor list, because the preprocessor doesn't use `{}` for grouping and we can just ignore the first and last elements) filled with scary memory initializer expressions (the hex constant is removed by `EAT`, and `MEM_INIT_BASE` removes itself). `<vmmem/protect_init.h>` of course doesn't exist and is commented out by the above line (this is actually a really obvious move and bad idea as most compilers don't enable trigraphs by default, but you could use another `#ifdef` trick further down, e.g. `#ifdef MEM_IN1T_BASE` or something like that).

With the surrounding constants self-removing, the list is just a non-ordered, non-uniform list of operator characters that can be queried by a relatively-conventional `SELECT` operation. For extra obfuscation, you could e.g. perform some preprocessor math on the incoming index to shuffle things around a bit more.

Opaque enough?

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, but sufficiently evil enough for me to mark as answered, especially since I asked "is there a way" instead of "how do I".